# I created an Array of Objects, but i cannot fill it

Tags: c#, xml, arrays

Edit: Thanks for the answers guys! I will check every answer as soon as i can (expect it to be 9 hours from now). to be honest, i didnt expect so many answers, so thanks to all of you. stackoverflow looks like a great community, im glad i made an account.

Here is my main program. And i seriously don't get it why this is not working... There is no error in Visual Studio, but as soon as i run the program, there is an Exception with Null Reference. But i created the Object! (datacoll)

```
public partial class frmClasstoXML : Form
{
    data daten = new data();
    dataCollection datacoll = new dataCollection();

    static int count = 0;

    public frmClasstoXML()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void cmdClassTOxml_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (string lines in textBox1.Lines)
        {
            string[] teil = lines.Split(';');                

            datacoll.data[count].logicalname = teil[0];
            datacoll.data[count].klarname = teil[1];
            datacoll.data[count].wert = teil[2];
            datacoll.data[count].writeable = teil[3];
            datacoll.data[count].readable = teil[4];
            datacoll.data[count].timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString();

            count++;
        }
        count = 0;

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(dataCollection));
        string writepath = "test.xml";

        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(writepath, false);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, datacoll);
        writer.Close();  
    }
}
```

And here is my data.cs file:

```
public class data
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("logicalname")]
    public string logicalname { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("klarname")]
    public string klarname { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("wert")]
    public string wert { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("writeable")]
    public string writeable { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("readable")]
    public string readable { get; set; }    

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("timestamp")]
    public string timestamp { get; set; }
}

[Serializable()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("root")]
public class dataCollection
{
    [XmlArray("chambers")]
    [XmlArrayItem("value", typeof(data))]
    public data[] data { get; set; }
}
```

My Program has a Textbox in it, with 5 rows (using multiline property of the textbox). I want to parse this textbox into this objects and create an XML File of it.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `count` as a static variable like that.  You should be using it as a local variable in the specific method using it.  This way different methods being used from that form simultaneously (possibly even from different instances) won't result in them fighting over that count variable, and it won't require you to initialize it to zero every time you use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you're never instantiating instances of `data`. You're creating the collection but it is simply a collection of references that *can* point to data objects. When you first create the collection they're all null.

```
   foreach (string lines in textBox1.Lines)
    {
        string[] teil = lines.Split(';');

        datacoll.data[count] = new data();  // call constructor              

        datacoll.data[count].logicalname = teil[0];
        datacoll.data[count].klarname = teil[1];
        datacoll.data[count].wert = teil[2];
        datacoll.data[count].writeable = teil[3];
        datacoll.data[count].readable = teil[4];
        datacoll.data[count].timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString();

        count++;
    }
```

By simply adding a constructor call you'll have new instance of data at `datacoll.data[count]` which you set the properties on. With your current code I would expect it to throw a NullReferenceException on `datacoll.data[count].logicalname`.

Also you need to allocate the array with some size in the constructor for datacollection. You could modify it to take an `int` call it length and do `this.data = new data[lenght]` or, if you want the collection to grow dynamically you could change the `data[]` to `List<data>` in which case the body of your foreach would be more like;

```
    datacoll.data.Add(new data { 
                                    logicalname = teil[0];
                                   //set rest of properties 
                                });
```

or

```
    data temp = new data();
    temp.logicalname = teil[0];
    // set rest of properties
    datacoll.data.Add(temp);
```

Comment: Ok, i changed the class to "List<data>" and changed the body of my foreach to             data temp = new data(); temp.logicalname = teil[0]; (rest of properties)... datacoll.data.Add(temp);. and i added the "datacoll.data[count] = new data(); Line. But now i got a NullReferenceException on the //call contructor Line.

Comment: @Valis that is most likely because `data` is null. To fix that you need to change the default constructor for `dataCollection`. Just add  `public dataCollection() { data = new List<data> }` to the class and everything should work.

Answer (score 0):

You create `datacoll` but I assume it starts empty. There is nothing at index `0`, or probably in `data`.

When you do,

```
datacoll.data[count].logicalname = teil[0];
```

Where does the content of the `dataCollection` class come from?

Comment: the data comes from the "class data". in runtime, the data comes from the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to initialize the array, as well as each of the items in the array:

```
datacoll.data = new data[textBox1.Lines.Length];

foreach (string lines in textBox1.Lines)
{
    string[] teil = lines.Split(';'); 

    datacoll.data[count] = new data();

    datacoll.data[count].logicalname = teil[0];
    ...
}
```

Comment: I added the two lines from your example and it worked perfectly. but in my big project, i have no idea how big the array will get (around 600-1000 objects). so first, thanks for your answer! and second, i try to make a List<> (see answer above).